# How to add query string at the end of the custom post type posts URL

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, function

I am searching for function How to add query string at the end  of the custom post type posts URL  for example:

```
www.example.com/post-type-category/post?abc=some_text&efg=some_text2
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you asking how to use `$_GET` variables?

Comment: It's something related to the query string as per my search @Grumpy

Comment: in what language do you want to do this ? javascript ? php ?

Comment: In any language if is in php i will use functions.php

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
var querystring = 'abc=some_text';
$('a').each(function()
{
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(href.indexOf("post-type-category/post") > -1) {
        href += (href.match(/\?/) ? '&' : '?') + querystring;
        $(this).attr('href', href);
    }
});
```

Other Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xQ8hA/4/

Comment: Will it add to all the posts ?